# How to change the header colour (color) of a Spark DataGrid in Adobe Flex?

Tags: colors, datagrid, header, flex-spark

Is there a simple way to do this? (Change the colour of the headings in a Spark DataGrid in  Adobe Flex. They are black by default)

I'm a complete beginner to FlashBuilder / Flex - and can't find any easy solution.

Comment: I found a blog post here - http://flex6packs.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/spark-datagrid-skinning-custom-column-header-colours/ - but I can't get this working. Seems like it's quite a complicated thing to do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog post now provides a code sample, and answers the question:

http://flex6packs.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/spark-datagrid-skinning-custom-column-header-colours/